# Does "Star Wars: The Force Awakens" Invalidate Some of EU / Legends?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, star-wars-legends

Does "Star Wars: The Force Awakens" invalidate some or most of the Star Wars Expanded Universe (EU) / Legends series of books, comics, games, etc?

Given that "Star Wars: The Force Awakens" is set about 30 years after the Battle of Endor and the events of "Return of the Jedi", it looks like its a safe enough time period where all the events of EU could have happened, and then the new movie trilogy.

In particular, EU has some elements that are eeriely similar to The Force Awakens:

- There is a Ben in the Skywalker family tree, who is a grand-son of Darth Vader
- One of Darth Vader's grand-children does fall prey to the Dark Side and becomes Darth Caedus
- Luke Skywalker does train and build a new generation of Jedi Knights, but their numbers often fall as a result of some galactic war (example: the battles with the Yuuzhan Vong across the galaxy, and Abeloth and her Sith acolytes)
- There are references to the ancient Jedi temple / home world where Luke Skywalker has gone into self-imposed exile by the time of "The Force Awakens"

Having said all that, it looks like there are also elements in "The Force Awakens" that invalidate some of the story lines. Just wondering if there is an explicit demarcation or any EU story lines that did get invalidated in the new Disney trilogy?

Comment: I think EU got de-canonized.

Comment: very related [how-aware-were-the-makers-of-the-force-awakens-of-legends-eu-canon?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111818/how-aware-were-the-makers-of-the-force-awakens-of-legends-eu-canon?rq=1)

Comment: Considering the events of the Truce of Bakura happen pretty much after the events of RotJ, I'd say it already violated the EU.  Also, The prequels pretty much violated the EU when they show that Geonosis and Mustafar were the places where the Death Star was built and designed, rather than the Maw.